# Table Column value in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two table

Employee

| EmployeeId | Name | Job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | David | yes |
| 124 | Timothy | yes |
| 125 | Maxi | No |
| 126 | Abie |  |

EmployeeResidence

| Id | EmployeeId | EmployeeSpclField | EmployeeSpclValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Married | yes |
| 2 | 123 | Nationality | MEX |
| 3 | 123 | Job | Fitter |
| 4 | 124 | Married | yes |
| 5 | 124 | Nationality | ARG |
| 6 | 125 | Job | Driver |

I need a Sql query that returns 1 or 0 based on the Bind value Employee id and I need the following conditions to be validated

1. job should not be null
   2)Nationality should not be null and he should belong to MEX

So how can i do that ?
I am building something like this

```
select 1 from Employee emp ,EmployeeResidence er 
where 
employeeid=:empid and emp.job is not null and
```

I am struggling to include EmployeeSpclField column value to check if it is not null and belongs to MEX

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: is this mysql or oracle?

Comment: i have removed mysql tag

Answer (score 1):

I might avoid a join and instead use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee e
WHERE Job IS NOT NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EmployeeResidence er
              WHERE er.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND
                    er.EmployeeSpclField = 'Nationality' AND
                    er.EmployeeSpclValue = 'MEX');
```

Answer (score 0):

Select a 0/1 flag

```
select case when exists (
    select 1 
    from Employee emp 
    join EmployeeResidence er 
      on emp.employeeid = er.employeeid and er.EmployeeSpclField = 'Nationality' and er.EmployeeSpclValue = 'MEX'
    where emp.employeeid=:empid and emp.job is not null ) then 1
   else 0 end flag 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select
e.EmployeeID,
case when er.EmployeeID is null then 0 else 1 end as return_val
from
Employee e
left outer join
(select EmployeeId,
 max(case when EmployeeSpclField='Married' then EmployeeSpclValue else NULL end) as married,
 max(case when EmployeeSpclField='Nationality' then EmployeeSpclValue else NULL end) as Nationality,
 max(case when EmployeeSpclField='Job' then EmployeeSpclValue else NULL end) as Job
from 
 EmployeeResidence
group by
EmployeeId) er
on e.EmployeeId=er.EmployeeId
and e.Job is not null 
and (er.Nationality is not null and er.Nationality ='MEX')
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be using conditional aggregation in order to count desired conditions

```sql
SELECT SIGN(NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN er.EmployeeSpclField = 'Nationality' 
                          AND er.EmployeeSpclValue = 'MEX' 
                          AND e.Job IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)) 
    AS Result
  FROM Employee e
  JOIN EmployeeResidence er
    ON er.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
 WHERE e.EmployeeId = :empid
```

where `SIGN()` function is used considering the possibility to have duplicate records for `Nationality` value for `EmployeeSpclField` column per any of `EmployeeId` column's value.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e829582a33e0afdb67f73031155192b)</kbd>